# Volly is giving me com.android.volley.AuthFailureError in Android

Tags: android

***CODE***

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

***PROBLEM***

This is my code in which I'm using the Volly-Library to get the JSON Object using the GET Method. I'm using Volly Library in my Android App to get the Json response using the Volly-Library. But it is throwing the AuthFailureError.

Comment: First test the api in Postman and see if you're getting a response. I guess AuthFailure means you may require authorization token while sending the request to get a response.

Comment: The Api is giving a valid Json Object in return.